# How do I become High King of Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible, by doing either of the civil war questlines to become the high king of Skyrim?

Comment: I think the answer is "You can't"...

Comment: This is actually REALLYYYY old, but there was a mod somewhere which allowed you to actually become one and command literally EVERY person in the game.

Comment: The reason why I edited your question is because that it doesn't make sense. Please accept the question.