# Is it possible to own a slave?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

As the question says, I'd like to know if it's possible to "buy" a slave and use it as companion (even if it's useless).

If not, is there any mod that implements this feature?

Comment: pretty sure this isn't possible without mods

Comment: Hey happy, I removed the second part of your question because it counts as a mod-recommendation, which isn't actually allow as per our [FAQ]. I've also turned it into a "how" instead of a yes/no since yes/no questions don't really work great here.

Comment: I rolled back the edit. This question should be closed, as it is based primarily on conjecture and not on any real evidence that the action is possible, it is functionally rhetorical, and not constructive, in much the same way as http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39003/how-do-i-become-high-king-of-skyrim and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34881/can-i-sleep-with-prostitutes

Comment: Closing this question makes no sense: I asked about a specific feature and also got a specific answer that solved my problem. Isn't this what this site is about, getting objective answers to objective questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Fallout 3 you could have some kind of [slave](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Slavery); in New Vegas it isn't possible without mods.

[This](http://newvegas.nexusmods.com/) is the place where you can find the best mods. It changes so keep track since good mods really take a while to be developed. For now these are notable ones:

- [Slavery simple](http://newvegas.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=43785)
- [Slavery expanded](http://newvegas.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=44156) (more functionality than the first one)